# How to find docs with arrays in which elements match some other element in another array?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, morphia

Not sure if this is possible, but here goes.

I have a MongoDB (using morphia to access it) with a table like the following (simplified for this example, but the concept is the same):

```
{name:"Product A", parts:[{sku:"W-01"},{sku:"Y-01", qty:2}]}
{name:"Product B", parts:[{sku:"X-02"},{sku:"W-02"}]}
{name:"Product C", parts:[{sku:"Z-01"}]}
```

Now I want to find products with parts of which sku starts with "Y" or "Z". For the above docs, the first and third should be returned.

One possible query I can imagine is like this:

```
{$or:[{"parts":{"$elemMatch":{sku:/Y.*/}}},{"parts":{"$elemMatch":{sku:/Z.*/}}}]}
```

This needs to loop through the query arrays ["Y","Z"]

Is there any other way to do this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a regular expression match, you *could* split out the first letter its own subkey as well:

```
{
    name:"Product A", 
    parts: [
        { s: "W", ku: "W-01" },
        { s: "Y", ku: "Y-01", qty:2 }
    ]
}
```

Otherwise you can simply do this regular expression match — you don't need the `$elemMatch` here either.

```
db.products.find( { "parts.sku: /^[YZ]/ } );
```

But it is better to use an `$or` for each of them, as then at least a little bit of the index can be used as the regular expression search is now a fixed-prefixed regular expression that internally gets rewritten to a range query (`Y <= x < Z`) or (`Z <= x < [`):

```
db.so.ensureIndex( { 'parts.sku': 1 } );
db.products.find( { $or: [
    { "parts.sku": /^Y/ },
    { "parts.sku": /^Z/ } 
] } );
```

Comment: Thanks @Derick, The sku field actually more complex to split. And I can't change the structure of the incoming source docs. But the regular expression way works and simplies the code. I will continue to use $or till better solutions found.